# cost of virtual calls with optimization

Tags: c++

I have a question about the cost of virtual calls when the type pointed to is always the same:

```
class Base
{
    Base() {};
    virtual void Func() = 0;
};

class Derived
    : public Base
{
    Derived() : Base() {};
    void Func() { /* Do something */ };
};

int main()
{
    Base* base = new Derived;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        base->Func();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Will the compiler optimize this virtual call away?

Comment: I would be more worried about the call to `new`.

Comment: This does not even compile. Please fix it.

Comment: You have to declare `Func()` in Derived as virtual so that the compiler knows it is linked to the `Func()` in the base class. Otherwise it would just define another function that would hide the function in the base class via "name hiding" which would work as intended when calling it on objects of derived, but calling the function on base class objects would call the base class function instead. Luckily here you declared it purely virtual so it won't compile at all since you never implement it. Also it needs a return type.

Comment: As far as optimizing it out, you should either profile it or if you know what you're looking at you could look at the assembly the compiler creates.

Comment: @RyanP I added return type. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanP There is no need to use `virtual` when implementing a virtual function in a derived class.

Comment: @janm Only if there was a third class deriving from Derived, right?

Comment: @Q-bertsuit No. Why do you think that?

Comment: @janm If you want to allow any children of Derived to override the Func() method, you would have to use virtual? Or does that only apply to non-pure virtual methods?

Comment: @BoPersson What's the problem with using new here?

Comment: @Q-bertsuit `Derived::Func()` is virtual because it is overriding `Base::Func()`. A class deriving from `Derived` which implements `Func()` would be implementing a virtual `Func()`.

Comment: @janm Ok, thanks for the explanation on that digression :-)

Comment: @Q-bertsuit - If performance is *that* important, allocating a dynamic object is *a lot more* expensive than a virtual function call. If the type is always the same, why not just create the object without the pointer?

Comment: @BoPersson Sometimes you have systems that can take as long as they want to initialize, but has to respond quickly to events. The reason I want to use a base pointer is for testing purposes with a MockDerived type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC with -O3 doesn't seem to optimize virtual call away.

https://goo.gl/TwZD6T

```
.L5  
    movq    (%rdx), %rdx
    cmpq    Derived::Func(), %rdx
    je  .L3
    movq    %rbp, %rdi
    call    *%rdx
    subl    $1, %ebx
    jne .L11
```

This does a function pointer comparison and if not equal goes ahead and do an indirect function call.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite hard to optimize away virtualness of a function. You cannot know at proper compile time that the virtual will not have any effect. It's only at link time you can figure that out.

What's more problematic is that you even then might not be able to know since you could possibly dynamically load shared libraries that implement yet another subclass which might override the virtual function.

Basically such optimization requires quite smart link-time optimizations, for what is probably quite small gain.

Answer (score 1):

VC++ like GCC doesn't Optimize the call away .
built with Visual Studio 2013 on release mode with /O2 flag:

```
    base->Func();
010B12D2  mov         eax,dword ptr [esi] //load V-Table 
010B12D4  mov         ecx,esi //load this pointer into ecx  
010B12D6  call        dword ptr [eax]  //call the first function in the V-Table.
```

***EDIT:***
your question actually demonstrated something very nice. `esi` holds `this`. how can dereferencing `this` gives the V-Table? well, because the V-Table is the first "variable" a polymorphic object have in it's memory. so assembly-wise , `*this()` actually produces a call to the first function, `*(this+sizeof(void*))()` calls the second function in the V-Table and so on.  
it's pretty much like declaring your class as

```
class A{
   VTABLE vtable;
   //rest of the variables.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the smartness of your compiler; perhaps it can optimise, perhaps not. It's also an implementation detail -- you care more about the overall performance of your code rather than specific details like this. Measure your performance and decide whether optimisation is necessary, and if so, your approach.

If you really care with code like this you have options like using the C++11 keyword `final`, and doing a test for the type outside the loop instead of just using vtable dispatch inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot optimize this virtual call away, because the symbol for the vtable for `Derived` is externally visible, and can be overridden at runtime using a shared object and the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable.

I think it should be able to optimize the call if you use the `-fvisibility=hidden` parameter.

Comment: Those obstacles you mention are implementation details. The impossibility doesn't follow because some implementation are constructed in a way that makes it impossible.

Comment: Look at the optimized code in the accepted answer. `Derived::Func()` is empty, and the compiler knows that, so if the call goes to that function, it is skipped, and the `je` directly goes to the start of the loop, so there must be a case where the function pointer is not going to `Derived::Func()`, otherwise no handling would be required. This case is when the symbol is overridden. The optimization is still suboptimal, because it could be pulled out of the loop, and the entire loop optimized out for the case where the function pointer is equal to `Derived::Func()`.

Comment: So your argument is that because this particular version of GCC generates that code there could not be any better optimizations? Guess what? Since it is known that `base` points to a `Derived` object and that `Derived::Base` does nothing a conforming implementation could possibly just skip the loop and all the `vtable` stuff out and just return from main (it would maybe need to call `operator new`, but that's all).

Comment: No, my argument is that the code is correct, because the ELF standard permits overriding symbols, so indeed it needs to resolve the virtual function call in every loop iteration (because an overridden `Derived::func()` might destroy the object and construct another in its place), and the optimization to use the inlined copy of the function is contingent on the virtual function call still being the same. [It could be done better though.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67886)

Comment: Using ELF is also an implementation detail, other compilers produces other kind of executables. My argument isn't that the code is incorrect in any way (it isn't AFAICT). My argument is that you can't conclude that such a optimization is impossible due to observations based on implementation details. In this example one can see that the only observable behaviour it has is that it exits and possibly calls `operator new` - a conforming implementation is allowed to just call `operator new(1000)` and terminate for this particular program.

Comment: Correct -- I'd even postulate that the call to `operator new` is not necessarily observable, and I believe there are compilers that know to optimize it out. Rereading the entire thread makes me also realize that I assumed gcc for some reason, when it wasn't mentioned.